# Visual Force page is not invoking lightning component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I have created a managed beta package for testing purpose and I have installed it on a newly created fresh org. The managed package includes a Visualforce page which invokes a lightning component.

While I am trying to preview the Visualforce page then the lightning component is not loading and showing an error in the console

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

And while I am installing the same package on an old developer org which was created approx 1 month before the Visualforce page is working fine and displaying the lightning component.

VfPage Code

```
<apex:page controller="abc" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">
<apex:includeLightning />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" lang="en" style="height:90%">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Display Data</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <apex:slds />
    </head>
    <body style="height:100%">
        <!-- REQUIRED SLDS WRAPPER -->
        <div class="slds-scope" style="height:100%" id="data">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
    $Lightning.use("{!namespace}:lightningApp", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("{!namespace}:lightningComponent",
                                   "data",
                                   function(cmp) {
                                       // do some stuff
                                   });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Most likely, the error is in the `getNamespace()` function (or the equivalent string attribute). Make sure you're in the correct namespace. If you want us to help you, we'll need to see your controller code from `abc`.